# Can not access jquery in function. "Variable Scope" issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

My ultimate goal is to have dynamic autocompletion on text input using typeahead jquery library.

In my HTML I put the input text field like this:

```
<input class="typeahead form-control" name="author_1" id="author_1" type="text"
               placeholder="Type a part of author name or surname">
```

then in javascript I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function typeahead_initialize() {
    var path = "{{ route('instructor_name') }}";
    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        source:  function (query, process) {
            return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {
                return process(data);
            });
        }
    });
}

typeahead_initialize ();

 // Here typeahead is recognized as a function

 // $('.typeahead').typeahead('destroy');  

// Begin jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addAuthorBtn").click(function() {
        addAuthor();
    });

    $("#removeAuthorBtn").click(function() {
        removeAuthor();
    });

    function addAuthor () {
        // Destroy the typeahead system
        // The problem is here: typeahead is not recognized
        // as a functon here. It seems I can not reach
        // jquery functions here.
        $('.typeahead').typeahead('destroy');

        // I add the dynamic input here, I deleted the unrelated code

        // Reinitialize typeahead system again to include
        // the dynamically added text input
        typeahead_initialize ();
    }

    function removeAuthor () {
        // Destroy the typeahead system
        $('.typeahead').typeahead('destroy');

        // I remove the dynamic input here, I deleted the unrelated code

        // Reinitialize typeahead system again to include
        // the dynamically added text input
        typeahead_initialize ();
    }

});
</script>
```

I explained in comment where the problem is. The auto-completion works for the first static input. But the second dynamically added input is not offering autocomplete, which I suspect I must destroy the typeahead and rerun it again. I guess the 'this' object inside addAuthor() function does not point to the same 'this' which is outside of $(document).ready(function() {}). How can I solve this? I cannot destroy and reinitialize the typeahead system when user clicks the add or remove button.

The official error I get is:

```
TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function
```

---

Update: 
This is not related to forgetting to include jquery library, these are the libraries that I have included so far (I am using Laravel so the formatting  is a bit odd) I guess it is related to "scope". The autocompletion actually works! so it means "typeahead" library is included properly. It just does not work when I call the typeahead from "inside a function".

```
<script src="{{ URL::to('js/jquery-3.1.1.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::to('js/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Have you included jquery library?

Comment: @user2181397.. It must be else would show error $ is undefined.. I think it is with the order of the js libs.. Put jQuery first and then the js for typeahead

Comment: Also, typeahead is not longer bundled with bootstrap..  include the the typeahead.js separately

Comment: yes I did. The latest one.

Comment: Is it possible you're loading jQuery more than once? Check the rendered source code for `<script>` tags as well as your browser's *Network* console

Comment: I checked. jQuery is loaded only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the problem by myself. The problem comes because I use Laravel and it adds some scripts via app.js at the button of my view that causes this problem.

Probably the Laravel framework adds jQuery library by itself and two instances of it causes this issue.Removing the Laravel scripts solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thing you did wrong is invoking `typeahead_initialize()` in script directly. Put this function in `document.ready` and all will go smoothly.

I just copied your code and did some modification check jsfiddle below, see log in `console` also

https://jsfiddle.net/Ld1wcy03/

Comment: It does not work. After moving  `typeahead_initialize()` into `document.ready` the JS error is: `jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).typeahead is not a function`

Comment: I still think it is an scope issue. Just do not know how to resolve  it. so strange.

Comment: it's working in jsfiddle and plunkr, Try changing loading order or scripts.

Comment: I think it is about Laravel framework. Somwthing is interfering inside there with jQuery UI library.

Comment: It was the fault of Laravel script. removing it solved it, thanks.